# Objects Position Not Matching Up (Spritekit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, frame, skscene

I am building a spritekit game and have just started the project. I have a circle on the screen which starts in the center, and when i drag my finger from the circle outward, it will show a dotted line/bezierpath connected to the ball which will help the user see where it is aiming the ball. When the user lifts their finger, the ball will shoot in the opposite direction of the aim line. (Think a game like soccer stars or pool). The issue is that the maneuver works the first time when everything starts in the middle: I drag my finger and the ball shoots in opposite direction then stops. But when I try it again, the position of the aiming line says it is the same as the ball (It should be), but then it shows up like an inch away from the ball on the screen. I feel like this may be an issue that the scene(s) behind the objects may not be the same size? But I'm confused because I think I'm only using one scene.

GameViewController viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.size = view.bounds.size
            //scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)


            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

GameScene Code (Doubt you need all of it but whatever):

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 35)
    var touchingBall = false
    var aimLine = SKShapeNode()

    var startAimPoint = CGPoint()
    var endAimPoint = CGPoint()

    let damping:CGFloat = 0.94

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        ball.fillColor = SKColor.orange
        ball.name = "ball"

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)

        var physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 35)
        ball.physicsBody = physicsBody
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ball.physicsBody?.friction = 10.0

        ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        self.addChild(ball)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("TOUCHES BEGAN.")
        for touch in touches {
            print("TB: \(touchingBall)")
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
            if node.name == "ball" {
                // touched inside node
                if ball.physicsBody!.angularVelocity <= 0.0{
                    touchingBall = true

                    startAimPoint = ball.position

                    print(touchingBall)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("TOCUHES MOVED.")
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if touchingBall{
                endAimPoint = location

                assignAimLine(start: startAimPoint, end: endAimPoint)
                print("Moving touched ball")

            }
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches ended. \(touchingBall)")
        if touchingBall == true{

            ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -(endAimPoint.x - startAimPoint.x) * 3, dy: -(endAimPoint.y - startAimPoint.y) * 3))

        }

        touchingBall = false
        aimLine.removeFromParent()
        print(touchingBall)

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        print("Touches cancelled. \(touchingBall)")
        if touchingBall == true{

            ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -(endAimPoint.x - startAimPoint.x) * 3, dy: -(endAimPoint.y - startAimPoint.y) * 3))

        }

        touchingBall = false
        aimLine.removeFromParent()
        print(touchingBall)

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

        print(ball.physicsBody!.velocity)
        let dx2 = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * damping
        let dy2 = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * damping
        ball.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx2, dy: dy2)


    }
    func assignAimLine(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint){

        aimLine.removeFromParent()

        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: start)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: shortenedEnd(startPoint: start, endPoint: end))

        var pattern : [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]
        let dashed = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.cgPath.copy(dashingWithPhase: 2, lengths: pattern))

        aimLine = dashed
        aimLine.position = ball.position

        aimLine.zPosition = 0

        self.addChild(aimLine)



    }
    func hypotenuse(bp: UIBezierPath) -> Double{
        var a2 = bp.cgPath.boundingBox.height * bp.cgPath.boundingBox.height
        var b2 = bp.cgPath.boundingBox.width * bp.cgPath.boundingBox.width
        return Double(sqrt(a2 + b2))
    }
    func hypotenuse(startP: CGPoint, endP: CGPoint) -> Double{
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: startP)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: endP)
        return hypotenuse(bp: bezierPath)
    }
    func shortenedEnd(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint) -> CGPoint{

        var endTemp = endPoint
        //while hypotenuse(startP: startPoint, endP: endTemp) > 150{
                endTemp = CGPoint(x: endTemp.x / 1.01, y: endTemp.y / 1.01)
        //}
        return endTemp
    }
    func addTestPoint(loc: CGPoint, color: UIColor){
        var temp = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 45)
        temp.fillColor = color
        temp.position = loc
        self.addChild(temp)

    }
}
```

I tried printing the frame size for the scene and it says 400 something x 700 something (I am testing on iPhone 6 Plus), and it says the UIScreen is same size so i don't know what issue is. Overall, I just need the aiming line to be on the center of the circle more than just the first time I try the maneuver. Thanks.

Comment: pretty sure the issue is in gameviewcontroller with the scene size not matching the screen size

Comment: screen size does not have to match scene size.  Scenes are there own little world,  and the ideal way is to make your game in 1 static size, and let the system scale for you.  i recommend removing scene.size = view.size

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok, can u pls help me figure out issue i have been stuck on it for hours

Comment: i am guessing it is how you are creating your BezierPath

Comment: do not move to the start point,  your start point should be relative to your ball and should always be `CGPoint.zero`

Comment: I believe you are going to need to convert your end point to that of the ball, not the scene. Then you need to add the shape node to the ball as well

Comment: BTW, I do not recommend constantly adding and removing SKShapeNodes.  I would use only one, and change the shape on it instead with `shape.path = newpath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments,  your problem was how you were laying out your paths.  The code below makes the path relative to the ball instead of absolute to the scene.  I also fixed the issue with creating new shapes every time.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 35)
    var touchingBall = false
    var aimLine = SKShapeNode()

    var endAimPoint = CGPoint()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        ball.fillColor = SKColor.orange
        ball.name = "ball"

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 35)
        physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody.friction = 10.0
        physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.94
        ball.physicsBody = physicsBody

        self.addChild(ball)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("TOUCHES BEGAN.")
        for touch in touches {
            print("TB: \(touchingBall)")
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
            if node.name == "ball" {
                // touched inside node
                if ball.physicsBody!.angularVelocity <= 0.0{
                    touchingBall = true
                    aimLine.path = nil
                    self.addChild(aimLine)

                    print(touchingBall)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("TOCUHES MOVED.")
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if touchingBall{
                endAimPoint = self.convert(location, to: ball)
                assignAimLine(end: endAimPoint)
                print("Moving touched ball")

            }
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches ended. \(touchingBall)")
        if touchingBall == true{
            ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -(endAimPoint.x) * 3, dy: -(endAimPoint.y) * 3))
        }

        touchingBall = false

        aimLine.removeFromParent()
        print(touchingBall)

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        print("Touches cancelled. \(touchingBall)")
        if touchingBall == true{

            ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -(endAimPoint.x) * 3, dy: -(endAimPoint.y) * 3))

        }

        touchingBall = false
        aimLine.removeFromParent()
        print(touchingBall)

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

        print(ball.physicsBody!.velocity)
        //let dx2 = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * damping
        //let dy2 = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * damping
        //ball.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx2, dy: dy2)


    }
    func assignAimLine(end: CGPoint){


        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: end)

        let pattern : [CGFloat] = [10.0, 10.0]


        aimLine.position = ball.position
        aimLine.path = bezierPath.cgPath.copy(dashingWithPhase: 2, lengths: pattern)
        aimLine.zPosition = 0



    }

    func addTestPoint(loc: CGPoint, color: UIColor){
        var temp = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 45)
        temp.fillColor = color
        temp.position = loc
        self.addChild(temp)

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if I want to make sure that the bezierpath can be dragged out no more than a length of 80 what should I write? (I should still be able to adjust direction, but I should to be able to drag the bezier path as far as I want for a ton of velocity when I let go)

Comment: Just check your distance of your end point,  if it exceeds 80, the you need to get the angle of the line using atan2, then use cos(angle) * 80 for x and -sin(angle) * 80 for y

Comment: Hmm you shouldn’t have to reverse the angle...  maybe because your velocity is going from end to start, not start to end. Well glad it works